# How to Remove filter in mobile and tablet view

Tags: filter

I don't need the filter in the list page in device whose width is less than 700px.
I tried using below media query but it didn't work. Is there anything should do further. Kindly help me.

```
@media only screen and(max-width:771px)
{
 col-left.sidebar{ display:none;}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
@media  screen and (max-width:771px)
{
  .sidebar{ display:none !important;}  //if the col-left is class 
 }
```

Comment: Yea I tried that too..! But am sorry it's not working.

Comment: can you post the html too?

Comment: try it without parent updated the answer kindly check..

Comment: No stills the filter is visible in mobile and tablet view

Comment: updated the answer try and feedback..

Comment: yea I tired your updated answer.

Comment: if it didn't effect try to delete `var/cache` folder..

Comment: Yea I cleared my cache but still...

Comment: do you have live link or working on local?

Comment: It totally depends  on your html element of that section,
Qaisar Satti answered it is partial right. @
Qaisar Satti , sidebar is hidden for all pages

Comment: Am working on local..